# unable to pass the imageid to the other page using get method

Tags: php, get

This might be a simple question but now i started working on `GET` method so I'm kinda new to it.

I have some images which are given some unique ids:

```
<a href="imageid.php?id=" . $b . "><imagetag></a>;
```

`$b` is the variable that stores the ID of the image.

Now I want to pass the $b variable value to `imageid.php`.

The link successfully opened `imageid.php` in my browser but the URL looks like `imageid?id=`. It does not display the id in the URL.

I also tried doing this:

```
 echo $_GET['id']; // in my imageid.php
```

... but it's not printing the id that I just passed to `imageid.php` using the GET method? Why?

Comment: anyways i found the mistake myself and i have solved  it thanks for you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really enough information in your question to give a full answer, but have you checked that $b is really holding the image ID? Also, are you side "echo $var = $_GET['id'];" wouldn't just echo whether or not $var was assigned to? (i.e. false or true).

Please provide the full code so I can reply with a better answer.

Comment: What I meant was have you tested that that is the case? It sounds like you just need to do some more testing and come back if you can't find anything. Try echoing the value of $b to the page before you insert it into the string to make sure it's set correctly. How are you getting the value of the ID? You still haven't given any information that can help others to answer the question.

Comment: i got where i stucked and i have solved it jack thanks anyways